# Finding sample mode with C#

Tags: c#, statistics, sample, mode

I have such a sample: [5,3,5,5,8,9,8,8,6,1]

And I'd like to find the mode(s). In this case 5 & 8.

I have implemented such a method:

```
static List<int> Mode(int[] array)
        {
            if (array.Length == 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Sample can't be empty");
            }
            List<int> result = new List<int>();
            var counts = new Dictionary<int, int>();
            int max = 0;
            foreach (int num in array)

            {
                if (counts.ContainsKey(num))
                    counts[num] = counts[num] + 1;
                else
                    counts[num] = 1;
            }

            foreach (var key in counts.Keys)
            {
                if (counts[key] > max)
                {
                    max = counts[key];
                    result.Add(max);
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
```

But the output is 1,3

What's wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by mode(s) ?

Comment: One issue is that you're adding the count to your list instead of the number.  But even if you fix that you'll end up adding the first key from the dictionary as it's count is higher than 1.  You need to determine the max first then find all the numbers with a count equal to that.

Comment: @Hazrelle Mode is the number or numbers that appear most frequently in a data set.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First you need to calculate the `max` in the first loop.  Then in the second you can find the numbers that have a count equal to max and add the `key`, not the `max` to your result.

```
static List<int> Mode(int[] array)
{
    if (array.Length == 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Sample can't be empty");
    }
    List<int> result = new List<int>();
    var counts = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    int max = 0;
    foreach (int num in array)
    {
        if (counts.ContainsKey(num))
            counts[num] = counts[num] + 1;
        else
            counts[num] = 1;
        if(counts[num] > max)
            max = counts[num];
    }

    foreach (var key in counts.Keys)
    {
        if (counts[key] == max)
        {
            result.Add(key);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: The most suitable solution, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You adding **values** of `counts` Dictionary, which are amount of same numbers in initial array:

```
foreach (var key in counts.Keys)
{
    if (counts[key] > max)
    {
        max = counts[key];
        result.Add(max);
    }
}
```

You probably want to add `keys` to see which numbers have duplicates:

```
// int max = 0; <-- not needed

foreach (var key in counts.Keys)
{
    // Check that number from initial array (key)
    // have duplicates (value is more than 1)
    if (counts[key] > 1) 
    {
        // Add to result not amount of duplicates (value),
        // but number (key) which has duplicates
        result.Add(key);
    }
}
```

It will give you **5** & **8** from **[5,3,5,5,8,9,8,8,6,1]** array.

Comment: While this works on the example data set for a set like [1,1,2,2,2] the Mode is [2], not [1,2].  Basically it's suppose to find the number or numbers that appear the most in the data set, not all the numbers that appear more than once.